# MYSQL and an independent GUI

Tags: mysql, database, user-interface

I am new to MYSQL and I am creating a database. Once i finish making it ,i want to give it a platform independent GUI where the client does not need to go through all the backend command lines to modify and add new entries. I am not sure about how to proceed . Any suggestions would be of great help.

regards

Comment: create a web application ?

Comment: Something like phpmyadmin maybe? But that's a developer tool.

Comment: So... a content management system? You'll need to either write one or use an existing framework.

Comment: for something quick and dirty I would suggest you look into query MySQL database with PHP. Make a page where user can input values and you query update based on them.

Answer (score 0):

**Use A a web application**

You can use a web application to allow users to interface with your database. that would be platform independent GUI. There are many frameworks you can use, [Ruby On Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/), [LAMP Stack](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu), [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/), etc.

but if you want to get something going quick and dirty I suggest just create [PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) page that connects to your database. For example this would be all the code needed to start interacting with your database:

```
    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'];
  echo "<br>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```